# Imagepng PHP reverse engineer

Tags: php

I have a question about it's possible to get the file location that's given to the imagepng function.

Let's say..

```
   www.example.com/picture.php
```

shows a PNG image. Is it possible to get the file location on the server?

Or is it impossible to track what I need to have?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

PHP script reads the source of an image file (or creates a new resource programmatically) and sends in response just an image's content. It's not possible to locate the source of the base file.

Answer (score 1):

Erm, no, because `imagepng` doesn't create a file unless you tell it to. In the absence of a filename to save to, `imagepng` just outputs the PNG data straight to the browser.